# Why is C++ still preferred to build heavy GUI apps over the latest dynamic languages?

Tags: programming-languages, c++

I see that most of the apps that include heavy GUI content are usually developed in C++. Most of the games/browsers are coded in C++.

Can't we just develop better GUI apps with the latest dynamic languages? I know java wouldn't be a great choice. But what about languages like python which are natively built on C? Aren't the latest languages supposed to be better than their ancestors? Why do we still have to prefer the age old C++ over the latest languages?

And I would also like to know, what is it that is responsible in C++, for the better speed of processing GUI? On the other hand what is it that the other latest languages lack?

Comment: Python is used.  There is a company based out of Iceland that has half-million subscribers.  The reasons C++ is used is because of the speed.  I also wouldn't call some of the things that are possible with C++ "old".

Comment: If you think that Java is a 'dynamic' language, then you're deeply confused about what that word means in this context.

Comment: @Mike Baranczak: Interestingly, most of the answers focus on the performance aspects. And in that sense, Java *is* a dynamic language, since none of the popular implementations perform any kind of static optimizations. In fact, the most widely used Java implementation which is used for GUI desktop apps is Oracle HotSpot (or one of its derivatives like IcedTea), which is actually just a slightly modified Smalltalk implementation.

Comment: She's fast, thats why, but be sure you know RAII and SBRM comes along with C/C++.

Comment: @Jörg: HotSpot is a 'slightly modified Smalltalk implementation'? This is news to me. What's your source for this?

Comment: @Mike Baranczak: That's a long story. Basically, there was a research project first at Stanford, later at Sun Research called Self. Self is a programming language in the Smalltalk family that is simpler, more powerful, more expressive and most importantly *significantly* more dynamic than Smalltalk. Because it was designed as a programming language to develop whole systems in (as all Smalltalk dialects are), including (but not limited to) desktop applications, servers, operating systems, device drivers, itself, it *had* to blazingly fast. So, the Self team invented a whole bunch of new ...

Comment: ... optimization techniques, and when the Self VM came out in 1987 (and even more so the second generation in 1992), it *was* fast. It was faster than any other Smalltalk VM. The Self system shipped with a lot of example code, and one of those examples was a Smalltalk interpreter written in Self, and even *that* was faster than any other Smalltalk VM. Self was faster than many C++ implementations at that time, and even competitive with C. Well, you get it. It was *fast*. However, Sun decided that they didn't have a need for an object-oriented programming language or a fast VM, so they ...

Comment: ... basically starved the Self project to death by drying up the funding. When the Self VM engineers left Sun out of frustration, they were quickly scooped up by a Smalltalk startup called LongView (more commonly known by the name of their most product, an optional static type system for Smalltalk: StrongTalk). LongView knew that they would never be able to sell static typing for Smalltalk, so they thought they would rather sell the fastest Smalltalk on the planet and then include StrongTalk in the package in a sort-of Trojan Horse kind of play. They also realized that none of the cool ...

Comment: ... optimizations the Self VM did were in any way particular to Self, but were applicable to pretty much any object-oriented language (or even just any language *at all*). So, the Self VM engineers got to work on a Smalltalk VM called the Animorphic VM. Again, the Animorphic VM was *blindingly* fast (and still is, actually, even though the codebase hasn't been touched in 15 years or so, it can still compete with modern high-performance Smalltalks, JVMs and .NET, *especially* if you take into account that it uses a lot less resources than those, since it was designed for 486s with 20 meg ...

Comment: ... of RAM. Anyway, the rise of Java lead to the demise of Smalltalk (well, actually, it was more the other way round: stagnation and infighting within the Smalltalk community lead to the demise of Smalltalk which lead to the rise of Java), and the LongView engineers realized that, from an implementation standpoint, Smalltalk and Java really are the same language. (Which is not surprising, considering that *the* main influence on Java was Objective-C (and not C++ as is often falsely reported), which in turn is just the Smalltalk object model duct-taped onto C.) So, they modified their ...

Comment: ... Animorphic VM from executing Smalltalk bytecode to executing JVM bytecode, and they ended up with (you guessed it) a *blazingly* fast JVM, in fact, probably still the fastest JVM on the planet. At the same time, Sun was struggling with their dog-slow JVM, which was threatening to stop the rise of Java dead in its tracks. So, just a couple of years after basically having fired them because their expertise was deemed useless, Sun bought LongView for quite a hefty price to gain access to the VM engineers' expertise ... again. And that's how Smalltalk actually *did* win in the end. ;-)

Comment: Interestingly, this is one of those very rare instances, where you *can* actually put an objective, quantifiable, measurable, exact price tag on management incompetency.

Comment: @Jorg, shame you can't type it into an answwer box instead of 7 comments :)

Comment: @JorgWMittag that's a great story. It's a pity that SmallTalk and Self declined like that. I'd rather have those then Java any day.

Comment: I contest the assertion that Objective-C's object model was more of an influence on Java than C++'s. ObjC's (and Smalltalk's) object model is based on message passing, where the message is actually an object with an identifier itself, and the object checks whether it can handle such a message, but can optionally just define a generic handler for messages or pass the message on to another object. C++'s (and Java's) model is based on simple indexing into a function pointer table associated with an object. So if Java is based on ObjC, the engineers did a horrible job.

Comment: I like C++ too. But Delphi with its VCL (visual component library) is Definitively much suitable for GUIs. Take a look at those guys. You can build a WordPad clone (fully functional) in 15 minutes. You would need months to do it in C++.

Comment: C++ has more useful maintained and production ready libraries that are focused on long term support.

Comment: C/C++ is what the Operating System is developed in for legacy purposes and so our CPUs need to run C fast (see CPU stands for C processing unit).  I bet if everyone started using Smalltalk, Python, .NET, Javascript and  JVM then maybe the CPU will get special instructions for virtual machines.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'm one of those people who write C++ GUI apps (mostly for windows). With Qt, to be precise. My reasons:

- I like C++. I'm a freelancer and usually I can choose my tools (lucky me!)
- In a managed environment you may have a hard time when you need to use some unmanaged code (long-winded WinAPI declarations in C#, anyone?)
- Fewer dependencies that are more easily deployed
- More control over everything.
- **RAII** (vs. GC). And even if I allocate with `new`, I rarely ever `delete` anything explicitly, because I use smart pointers or the `QObject` hierarchy.
- C++ is very exciting these days, I can't wait for a compiler to fully support the new standard.
- Speed (only at the end of the list. I know it's not that important for the GUI itself, but it *tends to be* speedier because C++ programs don't suffer from the overhead that runtimes, byte code JIT-compiling and similar technologies add to the program.)

As you can see, these are mostly personal preferences. I find it important for my work to be enjoyable and C++ provides that to me.

Comment: +1 Speed is definitely the top reason here, aside from personal preference. However, I like "C++ is very exciting these days". To address the *question-asker*, not @Tamás Szelei: Sure, computing changes quickly with new ideas, paradigms, technologies, products but the latest and greatest is not a virtue. C++ has been around for a while and it doesn't mean it is outdated, rather it has a long proven track record compared to newer technologies. The original Stroustrup text (the inventor's book) is heavy going but there are some nice books out there by others - check oreilly.com for example.

Comment: Late to the party, but can you elaborate on the "less/easily deployable dependencies"?

Comment: I have been using C++ for over 20 years.  Many new and great features are added since 11, 14, and 17.  You can almost use C++ as a scripting language and still get the benefit of fast speed.  When I work with BIG data, I almost have to use C++ because any other language there will be 10-1000 slower.

Comment: @KeminZhou - "any other language there" - Oh... Poor you. There are other languages that are faster than C++. take a look at Delphi for example. faster GUI, faster execution time, MUCH faster compiler. Don't make final statements if you cannot back them up.

Comment: +1, also c++ for interoperability to 3rd party libraries or APIs, application is not just gui, it needs to have functionality, c++ is good for adding low level system code, background tasks, manage processes/threads, files and dirs, sockets, ssh, ftp etc without needing to implement and maintain wrappers to higher level languages like python or C# (network access, file access, parse data, graphics)

Answer (score 36):

Because speed matters.

- *Games* use C++ for core tasks, where performance is important. They use dynamic languages for scripting tasks where flexibility is important.
- *Desktop GUI apps*: Visual Studio, for example, is written in .NET and not native C++. It seems to work quite well for an IDE, as the IDE itself doesn't need to do lots of performance intense tasks. (The compiler, linker and other tools are not necessarily written in .NET - though as wawa points out in a comment, some appear to be (e.g. VB.NET))
- *Browsers* need to be fast too. After all they are kind of a secondary OS. On the other hand, you can argue that large parts of Firefox are actually "written in" javascript, as the Mozilla framework seems to heavily depend on javascript.

To sum up: I would not say C++ is necessarily *preferred* but if you have a performance bottleneck you have to go closer to the metal and then you meet C++ (well, or C). Sometimes it will just be easier to do everything in C++ -- one language.

Comment: +1 Best answer: It's purely to do with speed as the top reason for using C++. Even Microsoft themselves concede that C++ is best for performance compared with c# and visual basic - see their into on their Visual Studio pages. A very close second is portability - if you use cross platform libraries such as Qt. Best answer also because it's objective rather than subjective.

Comment: Your second point isn't entirely true. The VB.NET compiler is writen in VB.NET and the F# compiler is written in F#. The C# compiler isn't but from what has been released about project Roslyn, I think the C# compiler is being rewritten in C#.

Comment: The visual studio gui (the chrome) is written (from vs2010) in c# and WPF. The solution explorer, build system, code browser and toolbox is written in c#/c++ with winforms. The compiler is written in c++.

Comment: For most desktop apps, only the rendering and layout engines (i.e., the View) need to be fast. The Model doesn't tend to have much time spent in it anyway, and the Controller spends most of its time just waiting for the user to do something (and few users can click as often as 10 times a second with any reliability).

Comment: @MartinBa: I'd note that current compiler for C# and VB (Roslyn) is written in C#.

Answer (score 20):

The GUI apps that you see written in C++ are generally done so due to legacy reasons. Python (with Qt or Gtk) is very much viable for GUI applications, as is C# if you work in a Windows house. When starting something new, either is *very* much preferred to C++ because of the lack of plumbing work that has to be done.

Comment: +1 existing code is important. It is rare to start completely from scratch when developing new programs

Comment: how is using Python with Qt any more preferable to using C++ with Qt? If I were to start a new project today, I'd still use C++ for the GUI. Because: a) It's what I know, b) it does the job well. Just because C++ has been around a while doesn't make it "outdated".

Comment: @TZHX: "It's what I know" is a viable argument. If that's not given, not having to look after memory management anymore is a huge performance boost, and it may offset the effort of learning Python even for a single project. Another reason for using Python would be cross-platformness - with C++, you have to be careful and take special measures, whereas python is likely to just work.

Comment: I don't see any advantages of using PyQt instead of Qt with C++ for someone who know C++.

Comment: C++ is likely to just work, also. With Python you have to worry about which version of python the user has installed, or worry about bundling it. There really isn't that much work to be done "looking after memory" unless you make stupid errors. I think lots of people give "memory management" as a big hindrance to working with C++ without actually knowing how much difference it makes.

Comment: @TZHX Same thing applies to C++ - "Just works" isn't exactly always true, concerning shared libraries, DLL hell, architecture mismatches, dependencies etc. That said, I really like C++ as a language, so this is not just harping from someone who don't like the language.

Comment: @tdammers - python just works, right upto the point where you suddenly need to talk to something outside the gui. Then you hope that the python lib written by X to talk to MSFT api Y actually  works.

Comment: @tzhx: I didn't say C++ was outdated. For select projects, it's definitely the way to go. However, the complexity of a C++ project will *always* outweigh that of a Python project. Thus, the ROI will always be greater if writing in a higher level language. Personally, I consider "because it's what I know" as an irrelevant argument: If the engineer in question is actually good, picking up Python is trivial.

Comment: @Demian:  The additional complexity and power of C++ may provide additional R to compensate for the increased I, depending on circumstances.

Comment: @David: Agreed (and +1 to your comment). Having said that, with computing power these days, there are very few applications (that I can think of) that require *that* much runtime optimization to warrant the additional complexity. Considering that even many games are moving to using scripting languages for subsystems like AI, UI (World of Warcraft for example) and such, where additional runtime cost is largely frowned upon, there aren't many GUI application that require even that level of speed, so the argument of additional power of C++ is lessened (imho).

Comment: @David (cont'd): But I do agree that there *are* specific cases where using C++ is the best option.

Comment: @Demian Brecht:  It's partly a matter of scale, partly a matter of complexity, and partly a matter of environment.  Modern computers theoretically have enough power (which doesn't explain why Firefox can use one of my two cores all by itself) that speeding up processing won't help for most single-user systems.  Where it does matter (really complicated applications, servers, embedded) it's a question of whether it's worth the extra development effort to reduce the run time, and that does happen.

Comment: @David: Couldn't have said it better myself.. In complete agreement :)

Comment: @TZHX: People make stupid errors. Clueless people work on software all the time, and even excellent programmers make mistakes. Using a language with proper GC means eliminating one of the hardest-to-debug sources of runtime errors, trading some performance and control on the way.

Comment: I'm not convinced that GC is that big of a plus.  I think that in most languages that implement it, it comes back to bite you in more obscure and tougher to debug ways than if you just handled GC yourself from the start.  There are also some quite good tools for finding memory issues in C and C++, for instance Valgrind.

Answer (score 20):

Because no matter how many performance tests .NET and the like crowds show, no matter how close they come in benchmarks, in the end, C++ app comes out on-top. It's faster at cold boot, it's snappier, and has more ways it can be improved.

I have heard numerous proofs at the project starting phases that .NET is the way to go, but once it's chosen, they always ended up being a heavy cludge.

Also, C++ nowadays is quite safe and quite easy to use, especially with frameworks like Qt or WTL.

Comment: +1: "Also, C++ nowadays is quite safe and quite easy to use, especially with frameworks like Qt ..." I totally agree: I think a big strength is not (only) C++ in itself, but the fact that (1) it is compiled to native code, (2) has a reasonable set of features (OOP, templates), (3) has very good frameworks like Qt. This compensates the fact that the language is rather large and difficult to learn: once you master a decent subset of the language and some good libraries, you can be really productive with it.

Answer (score 11):

Most of game **engines** are coded in C++. Also lot of browser **engines** are coded in C++. But the browser GUI is often coded using some lightweight script (JavaScript, Python). With notable exception of Source Engine, most games engines also use scripting languages (like Lua or Python). [for reference: [list of Lua scripted games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aLua-scripted_video_games)]

Also take popular C++ GUI library like Qt. In current version (4.7) it uses QML for the GUI. QML is basically JavaScript with Qt bindings.

So really there is no C++ *vs* dynamic languages, it's mixed.

Comment: [Citation Needed]. I know many games uses scripting languages to let users extend them, but as far as I know there aren't really many games using scripting languages for their release-binary-functionality.

Comment: @ProdigySim: I know of several that do. Off the top of my head, World of Warcraft (Lua+XML), Naughty Dog's Uncharted series (Lisp), the Unreal series (UnrealScript), games based on the Torque and Unity engines, Dungeon Siege, NeverWinter Nights, and many others. Data-driven games are becoming the norm, where the scripting host takes over most (if not all) UI features and game state from top to bottom.

Comment: @ProdigySim: even if it's hidden from normal users, doesn't mean that internally they don't use scripting engines. Basically game developers have two options -- create their own scripting language for models or use one of general purpose ones. Lua is especially good for games, as it's generally good for real-time systems.

Comment: Source engine uses Squirrel scripting language.

Answer (score 7):

C++ is statically typed. This allows to optimize code execution beforehand by having a compiler fit your abstractions to available system process on a given platform. Up to now, dynamic languages need an additional software layer (= the interpreter) which slows down access to system resources.

Answer (score 6):

First reason will be: (old) habit

Second reason: less reliability on Virtual Machines, interpreters that need to be installed, etc.

And there are still quite some excellent IDEs to develop code in C++.

Comment: '*still* excellent IDEs'.. I'd argue Visual Studio and Eclipse are cutting-edge and have pretty much been for a long while.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: I didn't say other language don't have them too.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that you have much more control over everything that happens. If you were going to write photoshop in C#, you would have serious performance problems for some tasks. In a lower level language with more control, you can take shortcuts, optimize where needed for things that are more intense. Of course this assumes you are using C++ in unmanaged code, not C++ in .NET.

See [here](http://amalp.blogspot.com/2007/10/performance-analysis-c-vs-c.html) for a quick example.

Comment: Adobe Lightroom, which is basically a subset of Photoshop, is written in Lua.

Comment: @Jörg: and the rest of it is C++.  in fact that's probably the best combination available, C++ for the foundation, Lua for the rest (althought i still prefer C over C++ for low-level things).

Comment: @Javier: Yeah, Lightroom is basically the image manipulation algorithms from Photoshop (which are probably written mostly in MMX/SSE assembly) and SQLite3 (which is written in pre-historic ANSI C for portability) glued together with Lua. Adobe also developed their own Lua IDE, completely in Lua. Does anyone know what graphics toolkit they use? AFAIR Photoshop predates pretty much all modern toolkits, so it's probably something home-grown?

Comment: no offense, but if you think ANSI C is prehistoric, you've been reading the wrong code samples

Answer (score 4):

Most of the reasons given are technical or "above the table"... here are business reasons or the "under the table":

distributing compiled code v.s. distributing source code.  when developing in c/c++ you distribute the binaries.  if you are developing in one of the modern languages, you distribute the source.  it is difficult to sell the idea of obfuscators to management who have to answer to shareholders/investors so don't bother.

stupid users:  at least in the minds of the management. they still perceive their users to be barely able to double click a "setup.exe".  If you include the installation of an interpreter as part of the setup, they will shake their heads from side to side.

old developers:  most people with experience have been around for a long time, and have not kept themselves updated.  they program in C++ and not in the newer languages, because they don't know the newer languages.

Comment: I would argue you are distrubuting source code when you release a .NET application.  Look at Visual Studio much of the interface is designed with WPF forms.  Some of your points are of course valid, much of today's management were yesterday's developers, the bad news much of today's frameworks are unlikely to be valid because of the changes to computers today.

Comment: Lots of people with lots of experience have gained their experience by keeping themselves updated.  They tend not to learn hot new languages (like Pascal in the early 1980s) just because they're hot, but only if they have a use for them or they have interesting ideas (Haskell, for example).

Answer (score 4):

I would extend the scope of the problem from GUI to software that is expected to be competitive. C++ imposes no tax on the target platform as it concerns processing power, installed runtime, frameworks etc. So it will work on more limited customer hardware than a similar solution written in a managed/interpreted language. In the case of a successful commercial software the cost of development (potentially higher in the case of C++) is amortized by the number of sales.

Additionally C++ usually offers direct access to system apis (like GUI) what gives the best opportunity to optimize utilization and differentiate itself from similar solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I think a lot of it has to do with the APIs for GUI toolkits.  All of them have a C/C++ API, but not all of them have (say) Python bindings.  And sometimes the toolkits themselves were written with C++ in mind, so even if they do have support for other languages they don't *fully* support them (e.g., they won't support a Python `tuple` as an argument).

Comment: Oh, they don't fully support them, because they don't want to, or have no time to implement that. Not because that's impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You are mentioning browsers and games as examples. Both of these are pretty performance critical applications, so having them in a low-level language for speed makes sense.

Many other applications are less performance bound and could easily be written in other languages. C# in particular seems to be used a lot. (And Obj-C, but it does not really qualify as high-level I guess. Better than C++ though.)

However, there is a certain lack of frameworks for the latest programming languages. For example, there is no viable native GUI library for Python, really. Sure, you can use PyQt or PyGtk and they work well, but in the end, that is only interfacing with C code again. Again, C# (and arguably Obj-C) seems to be the exception and maybe, MacRuby or IronPython could change that game.

Answer (score 0):

For a language to replace C++ or Java, it has to do what is sorely missed in these languages besides out performing them at their own strengths.  Also, huge investments have gone into these languages.  That means there is a standard C++ library on many platforms, which browsers, games and such programs can readily use.  So there is bound to be some inertia.  Languages tend to take off slowly unlike other pieces of software.

If you look at it, Anaconda (RedHat's installer program) has been around for 10 or so years, written in Python from the beginning.  Python was not this popular when Anaconda was new.

Google's Go (golang.org) is evolving very fast.  The compiler is yet to be bootstrapped.  For its popularity to take off, its library has to stabilise, compiler should be bootstrapped, and, more people have to use it.  I have heard one production program outside Google is written in Go and is reported to have had no down time yet in its life of just over a year.

Comment: Actually, there is a commercial Go compiler for Windows which is written in Go, so there *is* a bootstrapped compiler for Go. (It's still in closed beta, though.)

Comment: Oh, I was out of touch, then.  Thank you for telling :)

Comment: It's called [erGo](http://NewquistSolutions.Com/index.php/ergo) and is produced by a company called [Newquist Solutions](http://NewquistSolutions.Com/).